# The force required to push a 100-lb object along a 10degree inclined ramp

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

What would be the force required to push a $100$-lb object along a ramp that is inclined $10^\circ$ with the horizontal?

I know that $\left|F^2\right|=\left|F_1^2\right|+\left|F_2^2\right|$ But I don't see a second force. What to do with the incline number?

Comment: What are $F_1$ and $F_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Since the force is required to push the object, it means that there is a perpendicular force trying to push the object through the incline.

The formula used is $F=mg\sin\theta$

Where $m=100$lb, $\theta=10^{\circ}$

$F=100\times9.8\times\sin10^{\circ}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How could I figure it out if I did not know this formula? I was given a packet from a student and there is no formula like the one in this answer.

Comment: @Jinzu First draw a diagram, then find the components of a vector using trig functions of a right triangle. Then notice the forces acting on the object, their components parallel and perpendicular to the incline, the net force acting on the object and finally apply newton's second law.

Comment: @Jinzu This could be [helpful](http://zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/mechanics/forces/inclinedPlane/inclinedPlane.html)

Comment: @KeyFlex awesome link for beginners

Answer (score 1):

The weight  $mg$ is decomposed into two forces, $$mg \sin (10)$$ and $$mg \cos (10)$$
The $mg \cos (10)$ is perpendicular to the surface so it does not impose any effort in moving the object.

thus you need $$mg\sin(10)= 100(32.17) \sin(10)$$ force to pull the object.